# Comparing two values in same column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named login with the fields id and success (0 or 1).

I need to return only the ids where there are more entries with success at 1 than 0 (for each id).

So far I have only been able to make a query for #success, another for #hits and another that compares if #hits > #fail

```
/*returns: id, #hits */
SELECT id, count(*) AS hits  
FROM login u 
WHERE u.success = 1 
GROUP BY id;

/*returns: id, #fails*/
SELECT id, count(*)  AS fails
FROM login u 
WHERE u.success = 0 
GROUP BY id;

/*returns id, #hits, #fails, #hits > #fails? */
SELECT id, SUM(success = 1) AS 'Hits' , SUM(success = 0) AS 'Fails', SUM(success = 1) > SUM(success = 0) as 'hits > fails?'
FROM login u
GROUP BY id;
```

Having just one field, I can't make any direct comparison.

Is there any way to compare values from query 1 and query 2?

Can I change query 3 to just return where SUM(success = 1) > SUM(success = 0)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try something like this :

```
SELECT col
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY col
 HAVING SUM(col1) > SUM(col2)
```

Comment: HAVING SUM(success = 1) > SUM(success = 0) worked, thanks